# Mocha: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, requirejs, mocha.js

I'm running a test suite in Mocha, and I'm finding that I often get "Fatal Error: undefined is not a function", with no stack trace. The problem is usually deep in my code dependencies, and not in the test case itself. This is enormously difficult to debug.

Is there a way to turn on stack traces, or verbose errors or something? Or do I have an unusual or incorrect setup possibly?

The setup is JavaScript using require.js, running the tests in Node.

Answer (score 2):

Requirejs returns `undefined` for one or more modules if it comes across a circular dependency, so that might be your issue here. Try this:

```
npm install -g madge
madge --circular /path/to/your/javascript
```

That will tell you if it found any circular dependencies. I think it only checks `define()` statements but that's been enough to help me track down similar issues. Here's more info on madge: https://github.com/pahen/node-madge

Comment: I know my question is not in depth. The code runs and the tests run, it's not hanging or anything. Do you think this still might apply?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's possible. You could also try Node's debugger: http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html & http://erickrdch.com/2012/09/debug-a-nodejs-app-with-chrome-dev-tools.html although I'm not sure if it would help if you don't know where to set the breakpoint.